# Stuck with Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle

This is my first time installing Oracle 9i.

I want to create a simple database.

When I go to "Oracle Enterprise Manager Console" and add a database to the tree, I cannot access the database as I don't have a valid username/password.

After a lot of searching, I found that I need to create a new database repository. While I was creating the new repository, it asked for USERNAME, Password, and Service.

```
username : SYS/sys
Password : change_on_install
service  : <host>:<port>:<SID>
         : SYSDBA
```

This is not working.  I need proper guidance on how to get out of this.

Comment: Why are you learning on 9i - why not something slightly more modern, or at least supported?

Comment: look at express version (xe): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html

Comment: You should **really** (I mean *really*) use a supported version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you really sure that you want to be starting out with a desupported version of the database that is at least 4 major releases out of date?  It would seem much more useful to download a more recent version of Oracle from the Oracle Technology Network (OTN) and to start with that.  You can get the express edition of Oracle 11.2 completely free and the enterprise edition is free if you just want to learn the product.

Second, when you installed Oracle, it should have prompted you to create a database as part of the installation process.  If you chose not to create a database during the installation process, you should run the Database Creation Assistant (DBCA) to create a database now.  Note that what lots of products refer to as a "database" is more like a schema in Oracle.  In general, you would only have one Oracle database on your machine though that database may have multiple schemas.

What operating system are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Justin. Actually i was in a situation. and i had only oracle 9i with me. But Thanks to god. i came out from the situation. and now i am going to download oracle 11g. :)